# What encodings does Buffer.toString() support?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing an app in node.js, and see that I can do things like this:

```
var buf = new Buffer("Hello World!")
console.log(buf.toString("hex"))
console.log(buf.toString("utf8"))
```

And I know of 'ascii' as an encoding type (it'll take an ASCII code, such as `112` and turn it into a `p`), but what other types of encoding can I do?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The official [node.js documentation for `Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) is the best place to check for something like this. As previously noted, `Buffer` currently supports these encodings: `'ascii'`, `'utf8'`, `'utf16le'`/`'ucs2'`, `'base64'`, `'base64url'`, `'latin1'`/`'binary'`, and `'hex'`.

Comment: I looked there first, but skipped straight to the "toString()" section, thinking it'd have at least a link to the encoding it supported. I completely missed the top section about encodings. Thanks!

Comment: Related links:
* [buf.toString(...)](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end)
* [Buffers and Character Encodings](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings)

Comment: Actually stack overflow is even more convenient than searching the documentation. IMO.

Comment: Why binary is not the binary 100110000 etc i'm though it ??

Comment: Binary here means individual bytes. If you want binary representation of individual bytes, you will need to call `.toString(2)` on each numeric byte value (something you can do without converting the Buffer to a string first).

Answer (score 22):

As is always the way, I spent a while Googling but found nothing until after I posted the question:

http://www.w3resource.com/node.js/nodejs-buffer.php has the answer. You can use the following types in `.toString()` on a buffer:

- `ascii`
- `utf8`
- `utf16le`
- `ucs2` (alias of `utf16le`)
- `base64`
- `binary`
- `hex`

Answer (score 1):

It support `ascii , utf-8 , ucs2, base64, binary`

Comment: And as per my answer above (which I discovered after a few pages of Googling, but seconds after submitting my question), it also supports utf16le (which is an alias of ucs2). Also, there's no hyphen in utf-8 when using it as a `.toString()` parameter for a buffer :)