# how to uglify a file and save to another location (vue.js)

Tags: node.js, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-2

I am unsure on how to uglify my `server.js` file and save it into the `dist` folder under a `server` folder. Right now I'm just using the `CopyWebpackPlugin`

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  {
    from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
    to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
    ignore: ['.*']
  },
  {
    from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/server'),
    to: config.build.assetsServerDirectory,
    ignore: ['*.sql']
  }
]),
```

This works, but is just a simple copy and paste.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**uglify-es**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es) + [**copy-webpack-plugin**'s `transform()`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#transform):

- Install the package:

  ```
  npm install uglify-es --save-dev
  ```
- Add it to your source:

  ```
  const UglifyJS = require("uglify-es");                  // add the require

  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {
      from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
      to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
      ignore: ['.*']
    },
    {
      from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/server'),
      to: config.build.assetsServerDirectory,
      transform: function (content, path) {               // add transform()
        return UglifyJS.minify(content.toString()).code;  // use uglify
      },                                                  // (no args = mangle+compress)
      ignore: ['*.sql']
    }
  ]),
  ```

Note: `UglifyJS.minify(content.toString()).code` is the same as `UglifyJS.minify(content.toString('utf8')).code`. [There are options in case of different encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34476862/1850609).

Comment: I guess the error when I try that `ERROR in Data must be a string or a buffer`

Comment: Ah, okay, had to fix the return to `return UglifyJS.minify(content.toString()).code;`. See the updated answer.

Comment: That worked, thanks. Any idea why the `uglify-js` package doesn't work? And sorry about the weird English.

Comment: `uglify-js` is for ES up to 5. From ES6 (ES2015) and above, it is `uglify-es`. You probably have things like `let` or arrow functions.

Comment: ah yep, makes sense then. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of help! :)

Comment: one last question, what should I do if I want to output the files into a single file? I tried changing it to `return uglifyjs.minify(content.toString('utf8'), { mangle: false, output: "server.js" }).code` but it gives the `Data must be a string or buffer` error again. I can ask a new question if you like.

Comment: Actually, and unfortunatelly, copy-webpack-plugin [doesn't do file merging by design](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin/issues/154#issuecomment-341320606). That means the `transform` function is always called once for each file. You would have to resort to more elaborated solutions like another `entry`.

Comment: would you know enough to show me? When I tried, it just tried to compile all the requires, like `fs` and such, which resulted in like a 3mb file. I can ask a new question.

Comment: Sure, I will try to help you out the best I can. If you want to try that path, I do suggest you create a new question, more importantly because you could paste more details there (like a small sample of what `server.js` and other files would be - I didn't know you used `fs`, for instance) and because maybe more people could help out as well (but I do will).

Answer (score 0):

There is a library already ready for that. You can use 
[uglifyjs-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin)

Then output the bundled file to your desired directory

If you don't like using the plugin. You can use Webpack's default uglifier.

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

    module.exports = {
      entry: {
        "bundle": "./server/server.js",
      }
      output: {
        path: "./dist",
        filename: "[name].js"
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          include: /\.js$/,
          minimize: true
        })
      ]
    };
```

Comment: don't think this works because I've already got an `entry` and `webpack-merge` is involved.