# How can I get the value in utf-8 from an axios get receiving iso-8859-1 in node.js

Tags: node.js, utf-8, character-encoding, axios, iso-8859-1

I have the following code:

```
const notifications = await axios.get(url)
const ctype = notifications.headers["content-type"];
```

The ctype receives "text/json; charset=iso-8859-1"

And my string is like this: "'Ol� Matheus, est� pendente.',"

How can I decode from iso-8859-1 to utf-8 without getting those erros?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`text/json; charset=iso-8859-1` is not a valid standard content-type. `text/json` is wrong and JSON must be UTF-8.

So the best way to get around this at least on the server, is to first get a buffer (does axios support returning buffers?), converting it to a UTF-8 string (the only legal Javascript string) and only then run `JSON.parse` on it.

Pseudo-code:

```
// be warned that I don't know axios, I assume this is possible but it's
// not the right syntax, i just made it up.
const notificationsBuffer = await axios.get(url, {return: 'buffer'});

// Once you have the buffer, this line _should_ be correct.
const notifications = JSON.parse(notificationBuffer.toString('ISO-8859-1'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the anser!! The JSON.parse worked just fine, but I had to change from **'ISO-8859-1'** to **latin1** for sintaxes ajustments. 



`axios({
                method:'GET',
                url:url,
                responseType:'arraybuffer',
              })
                .then(function (response) {
                  console.log(response.data);
                  console.log(JSON.parse(response.data.toString('latin1')))
                });`

Comment: Glad I helped you get there!

Comment: Good answer but JavaScript strings are UTF-16.

Comment: @TomBlodget javascript *engines* might use UTF-16 under the hood, and there are some leaky abstractions... Javascript strings generally are UTF-8-ish.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, but [this useful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863124/how-can-i-get-the-value-in-utf-8-from-an-axios-get-receiving-iso-8859-1-in-node#comment92642427_52863198) did:

```js
const axios = require("axios"); // 1.4.0

const url = "https://www.w3.org/2006/11/mwbp-tests/test-encoding-8.html";

axios
  .get(url, {responseType: "arraybuffer"})
  .then(({data}) => {
    console.log(data.toString("latin1"));
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

If your response is JSON, then you can parse it with `JSON.parse(data.toString("latin1"))`.

See [this list of encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476754/what-encodings-does-buffer-tostring-support) supported by `.toString()`.

However, an even simpler approach specific to Node.js is to set the `responseEncoding` [request configuration](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) key:

```js
axios
  .get(url, {responseEncoding: "latin1"})
  .then(({data}) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

---

Since `fetch` is now standard in both Node 18+ and the browser, here's an example (error handling and `JSON.parse()` omitted):

```js
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
  .then(buffer => {
    const data = new TextDecoder("iso-8859-1").decode(buffer);
    console.log(data);
  });
```